# How to set the confidence level for cross correlation using ccf in R

Tags: r, correlation, cross-correlation

In ccf, When I give the option of plot=TRUE, I will get a plot that gives me 95% confidence interval cut-offs for my cross-correlations at each lag. 
My question is, if I want to use a 90% confidence level, how can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: If helps if you include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data and the code you are running. Make it clear which packages and functions you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that by setting `Plot=T`, **ccf** function passes its results to **acf** and then to **plot.acf** function. **plot.acf** is where confidence interval is calculated. You can see it with the ":::" device

```
stats:::plot.acf
```

You should see something simmilar:

```
function (x, ci = 0.95, type = "h", xlab = "Lag", ylab = NULL .....etc.
```

I suggest you set `plot=F` in ***ccf*** function, then use **plot** function seperately, changing confidence interval **(ci)**. You can do so by using this code:

```
plot(x, ci = 0.90, type = "h", xlab = "Lag", ylab = NULL,
 ylim = NULL, main = NULL,
 ci.col = "blue", ci.type = c("white", "ma"),
 max.mfrow = 6, ask = Npgs > 1 && dev.interactive(),
 mar = if(nser > 2) c(3,2,2,0.8) else par("mar"),
 oma = if(nser > 2) c(1,1.2,1,1) else par("oma"),
 mgp = if(nser > 2) c(1.5,0.6,0) else par("mgp"),
 xpd = par("xpd"),
 cex.main = if(nser > 2) 1 else par("cex.main"),
 verbose = getOption("verbose"),
 ...)
```

LINK:
https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/plot.acf.html

Since you havent provided any actual example data, i will show you an example with two common time series: recruit.dat and soi.dat. Just run this script line by line and try to understand what each line does.

```
#import data from web:
soi = ts(scan("http://anson.ucdavis.edu/~shumway/soi.dat"), start=1950,   frequency=12)
rec = ts(scan("http://anson.ucdavis.edu/~shumway/recruit.dat"), start=1950, frequency=12)

#run simple ccf function with plot=F
ccfvalues =ccf (soi, rec, plot=F)

#now run a plot function, with the desired confidence interval. Simple as that!
plot (ccfvalues, ci=0.90, type = "h", xlab = "Lag", ylab = NULL,ylim = NULL, main = NULL,ci.col = "blue", ci.type = c("white", "ma"),max.mfrow = 6, ask = Npgs > 1 && dev.interactive(),mar = if(nser > 2) c(3,2,2,0.8) else par("mar"),oma = if(nser > 2) c(1,1.2,1,1) else par("oma"),mgp = if(nser > 2) c(1.5,0.6,0) else par("mgp"),xpd = par("xpd"),cex.main = if(nser > 2) 1 else par("cex.main"),verbose = getOption("verbose"))
```

Replace the soi and recruit data with your own and you are all set!
Hope it works!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I get this error when using the plot() function you give me as an example.
      ccf=ccf(mei[,2],n.mt1021960[,names(n.mt1021960)=='Annual'])
Then I replace the x in your plot() function with ccf, and I get this:
      Error: '...' used in an incorrect context. Could you help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: x should be replaced with your results!

Comment: Thanks. My code is,
ccf=ccf(mei[1:62,2],n.mt1024638[2:63,names(n.mt1024638)=='Winter'])      plot(ccf, ci = 0.90, type = "h", xlab = "Lag", ylab = NULL,ylim = NULL, main = NULL,ci.col = "blue", ci.type = c("white", "ma"),max.mfrow = 6, ask = Npgs > 1 && dev.interactive(),mar = if(nser > 2) c(3,2,2,0.8) else par("mar"),oma = if(nser > 2) c(1,1.2,1,1) else par("oma"),mgp = if(nser > 2) c(1.5,0.6,0) else par("mgp"),xpd = par("xpd"),cex.main = if(nser > 2) 1 else par("cex.main"),verbose = getOption("verbose"),...)
      Error: '...' used in an incorrect context

Comment: Hey Yang! Since you haven't provided any actual data, and i dont know what mei and Winter are, i can give you a simple example: it is now included on the bottom of my answer. You can run the code provided and see for yourself.

Comment: Thanks a  lot. I notice that you delete "..." in your original code just behind verbose = getOption("verbose"). Thank you so much.